# Testing source generator

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to test source generator.
Generator:

```
[Generator]
public class CustomGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context) { }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
              Compilation inputCompilation = CreateCompilation(@"
namespace MyCode
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    } 
}
");   
            var generator = new CustomGenerator();
             
            var driver = CSharpGeneratorDriver.Create(generator);
             
            driver.RunGeneratorsAndUpdateCompilation(inputCompilation, out var outputCompilation, out var diagnostics);

            static Compilation CreateCompilation(string source)
                => CSharpCompilation.Create("compilation",
                    new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source) },
                    new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Binder).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location) },
                    new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication));
```

The problem is that context.SyntaxReceiver always is null, how to fix that?

Comment: You need to first register a syntax receiver in your `Initialize` method, by calling `context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications`. See [the cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's inspect the definition of the [GeneratorExecutionContext.SyntaxReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.generatorexecutioncontext.syntaxreceiver) Property:

```cs
namespace Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
{
    public readonly struct GeneratorExecutionContext
    {
        // Summary:
        //     If the generator registered an Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISyntaxReceiver during
        //     initialization, this will be the instance created for this generation pass.
        public ISyntaxReceiver? SyntaxReceiver { get; }
    }
}
```

We see that the `GeneratorExecutionContext.SyntaxReceiver` Property is declared as *nullable*, meaning that there are cases where it is indeed expected to be null.
The documentation comment reveals that we first have to register our [ISyntaxReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.isyntaxreceiver) in [ISourceGenerator.Initialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.isourcegenerator.initialize).

As [canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086121/canton7) has pointed out, we first need to register it via the [GeneratorInitializationContext.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.generatorinitializationcontext.registerforsyntaxnotifications) Method:

```cs
[Generator]
public class CustomGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(static () => new CustomReceiver());
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        Debug.Assert(context.SyntaxReceiver is not null, $"No {nameof(ISyntaxReceiver)} registerd via {nameof(GeneratorInitializationContext.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications)}.");

        if (context.SyntaxReceiver is not CustomReceiver receiver)
        {
            return;
        }

        Debug.Assert(receiver is not null);

        //...
    }
}

internal sealed class CustomReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
{
    public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
    {
    }
}
```

Keep in mind to avoid expensive operations within the `ISyntaxReceiver` because it does not support *cancellation* unlike the *Generator* itself.